# Is the webview on Microsoft surface 3 hardware-accelerated?

Tags: css, cordova, gpu, surface

I'm creating a Cordova application that runs on Surface 3 but the performance is very bad, and when I profile the app the GPU usage stays at 0...
I'm using a lot of CSS3 transforms that should trigger the GPU but only the CPU is heavily used.

Any idea if this is the normal behavior? (Notice that if I run my app on edge on the tablet the performance is good...)

Is there a way to activate the hardware acceleration in VS?